# Join 2 table to add another table , sales total

Tags: php

How to add the total cost of the purchase items in my table?
I want to add another row , where in the sales total , of the user who bought the specific items to the supplier.

sales_detail table.

[image]

sales table.

[image]

Sample photo of where i want to add the total price
[image]
This would be a big help , thank you guys!

This is my php file.

```
 <h1 class="page-header">Product Sales Report</h1></center>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <center>
 <form action="total_sales.php" method="post">
  From: <input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="E.G.(2018-01-14)" name="dayfrom" required pattern="[0-9]{4}+[0-9]+[0-9]"> To: <input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="E.G.(2018-02-11)" name="dayto" required pattern="[0-9]{4}+[0-9]+[0-9]">
  <input type="submit" value="Show Sales" name="salesbtn" ></form></center>

            <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="prodTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="hidden"></th>
                        <th>Purchase Date</th>
                        <th>Customer</th>
                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                    $sq=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from sales_detail left join product on product.productid=sales_detail.productid left join sales on sales.salesid=sales_detail.salesid left join customer on sales.userid=customer.userid where product.supplierid='".$_SESSION['id']."' order by sales.sales_date desc");;
                    while($sqrow=mysqli_fetch_array($sq)){

                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="hidden"></td>
                            <td><?php echo date('M d, Y h:i A',strtotime($sqrow['sales_date'])); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $sqrow['customer_name']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $sqrow['product_name']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $sqrow['sales_qty']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a conditional statement inside the while loop to output the sales total for a user of specific products.

**Updated Code:**

```
<h1 class="page-header">Product Sales Report</h1></center>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <center>
 <form action="total_sales.php" method="post">
  From: <input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="E.G.(2018-01-14)" name="dayfrom" required pattern="[0-9]{4}+[0-9]+[0-9]"> To: <input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="E.G.(2018-02-11)" name="dayto" required pattern="[0-9]{4}+[0-9]+[0-9]">
  <input type="submit" value="Show Sales" name="salesbtn" ></form></center>

            <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="prodTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="hidden"></th>
                        <th>Purchase Date</th>
                        <th>Customer</th>
                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                    $sales_total_id = array();

                    $sq=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from sales_detail left join product on product.productid=sales_detail.productid left join sales on sales.salesid=sales_detail.salesid left join customer on sales.userid=customer.userid where product.supplierid='".$_SESSION['id']."' order by sales.sales_date desc");
                    while($sqrow=mysqli_fetch_array($sq)){
                        if( !isset( $sales_total_id[$sqrow['salesid']] ) ) {
                            $sales_total_id[$sqrow['salesid']] = TRUE;
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                            <td colspan="5" align="center"><strong>Sales Total: <?php echo $sqrow['sales_total']; ?></strong></td> 
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="hidden"></td>
                            <td><?php echo date('M d, Y h:i A',strtotime($sqrow['sales_date'])); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $sqrow['customer_name']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $sqrow['product_name']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $sqrow['sales_qty']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thank you very much , it works not. :). Slight design error only with the sales total transferring below not beside the table . Thank you